# CONTAINSTABLE predicate fails when invoked several times in short time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I've got a pretty curious problem...
I have written a stored procedure with a CONTAINSTABLE predicate; something like

```
SELECT dbo.MyTable.MyPK
FROM   dbo.MyTable INNER JOIN
       CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.MyTable, FullTextField, 'mysearch') AS tbl1 
            ON tbl1.[KEY] = dbo.MyTable.MyPK
```

If I run this SP with SQL Server Management Studio, it's all ok.

Now I've prepared an automatic test suite to try the effectiveness of my work under heavy weight...
I call my SP several times, with different parameters, for a bunch of times, and here there's the problem: if I launch my test suite, it fails returning a wrong result (e.g. 1 result while I'm expecting 3 results, and so on...). But if I launch my test suite in debug mode, stepping through my test code, no errors occur. Moreover, if I catch the wrong result and try to re-execute the SP that gave the wrong result (simply placing a conditional breakpoint on the error condition and dragging the execution pointer on visual studio...), the re-execution returns the right result!!!

What can I do???

Any ideas?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Bye cghersi

Comment: Are you manipulating the full text indexes in these test runs? Those indexes take time to build, and *aren't* necessarily fully constructed when their associated statement completes. Single-stepping/re-running would obviously give more time for the indexing operations to complete

Comment: That was exactly the point!! I added a sleep of 5 seconds in my test suite and now it's all ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are, I believe, system views that you can query to discover whether indexes are up to date - I don't know them off the top of my head - but they'd be better than including a fixed delay in your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously running the same statement against your database should not yield different results with all else being the same. Something is changing.

Run SQLProfile while you're stepping through your code to confirm that:

1. The SQL you think you're sending to the database is what is actually hitting the database
2. No other users are updating the database while you're stepping

Make sure in your profile trace that you can identify the connection that you're using (an easy way is to alter your connection string by setting the app name).  When you're stepping through your code watch the profile trace.  Copy the SQL that you see there into SSMS and run it directly to confirm results.  At the end of the day you should be able to isolate this to raw TSQL running in SSMS to find out where the problem is.